# Tuple with addition and multiplication

Tags: python

```
var = ((1,2),)
var = var + 2 * var[0]
print(len(var))
```

Output is 5.

Can someone please explain how the result of above tuple is 5?
`((1, 2), 1, 2, 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

```
var = ((1,2),)
var = var + 2 * var[0]
```

The equivalent of the code above is:

```
var1 =  2 * var[0] #the result of this is (1, 2, 1, 2)
var2 = var + var1 # this appends tuple(var1) to index one in var
```

the result of var2 is `((1, 2), 1, 2, 1, 2)`
and of course var2 has five elements in it

Answer (score 0):

*var* is a tuple which contains a single tuple.  When you say *var*[0], you are accessing that inner tuple, which is (1,2)
When you say `2 * var[0]`, you are doubling that inner tuple, which concatenates it. So `2 * var[0]` is `(1, 2, 1, 2)`
You are also appending that to the original tuple (1,2), which gives the ((1,2), 1, 2, 1, 2)
The final result is a tuple. That tuple has five elements: the first is a tuple, and the second, third, fourth, and fifth are each integers.

Answer (score 0):

You show yourself that the resulting tuple is:

```
((1, 2), 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

and the length of that tuple is clearly `5`...the first element being another tuple, and the remaining elements being integers.